# Downloading multiple files in phonegap using jquerymobile

Tags: android, ios, cordova, mobile, download

As the title says : Is there any way to download multiple files in phonegap using jquery mobile?

for example clicking a link, and download a hole repository?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using  Phone gap FILE API File transfer Object

If you want to download multiple file then you can use file transfer in looping or if download file is zip format then it will easy for you with file transfer and [extract zip plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/ExtractZipFile)

Method 1>

sample File transfer code:

configured Zip plugin then apply this code

```
function download(remoteFile)
{
      var localFileName = remoteFile.substring(remoteFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fileSystem) {
              fileSystem.root.getFile(localFileName, { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {
                  var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
                  console.log("localPath1:" + localPath);
                  if (device.platform === "Android" && localPath.indexOf("file://") === 0) {
                      localPath = localPath.substring(7);
                  }
                  console.log("localPath2 save:" + localPath);
                console.log("thid is localFileName :"+localFileName);
                  extractFile(localFileName); //No need for other formated file except zip file.
                  var ft = new FileTransfer();
                  ft.download(remoteFile,
                      localPath, function (entry) {
                          console.log("file path:" + entry.fullPath);
                          var linkopen = document.getElementById("openlink");
                          linkopen.style.display = "block";
                          linkopen.href = entry.fullPath;
                          var zippath = entry.fullPath;
                          console.log(zippath);
                          $("#btnExtract").show();

                      }, fail);
              }, fail);
          }, fail);
       console.log("completed");
}
```

*here written this code as consideration of Zipfile. you need to change code.

Method 2 :  delete

> extractFile(localFileName);

from code